# Azure MySQL server - MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Got packets out of order

Tags: java, mysql, azure, azure-appservice

When trying to connect to the Azure MySQL database server from the Java application, the following exception is thrown (code snippet below).

Confirmed the connection string : Host name, port number, username and password looks fine.

Tried the following steps, still getting the exception:

1. Changed the mysql-connector version to latest (5.1.36, 5.1.45 and 5.1.49)
2. Increased the max-connections parameter of the MySQL Database server
3. Updated the wait_timeout parameter of the mysql-server to 28800

Able to connect my local MySQL database server from the same Java application.
Java SDK - Java 8
MySQL server : 5.6
Tomcat server : 8.5.41

**Exception:**

```
020-09-14T15:00:32.411104974Z: [ERROR]         Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Got packets out of order
2020-09-14T15:00:32.411109175Z: [ERROR]                 at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor39.newInstance(Unknown Source)
2020-09-14T15:00:32.411119776Z: [ERROR]                 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
2020-09-14T15:00:32.411123976Z: [ERROR]                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
2020-09-14T15:00:32.411127976Z: [ERROR]                 at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
2020-09-14T15:00:32.411131977Z: [ERROR]                 at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
2020-09-14T15:00:32.411135977Z: [ERROR]                 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1013)
2020-09-14T15:00:32.411140077Z: [ERROR]                 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3609)
2020-09-14T15:00:32.411144077Z: [ERROR]                 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3541)
2020-09-14T15:00:32.411148078Z: [ERROR]                 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2002)
2020-09-14T15:00:32.411152078Z: [ERROR]                 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2163)
2020-09-14T15:00:32.411156178Z: [ERROR]                 at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2618)
2020-09-14T15:00:32.411160379Z: [ERROR]                 at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2568)
2020-09-14T15:00:32.411164379Z: [ERROR]                 at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1557)
2020-09-14T15:00:32.411168379Z: [ERROR]                 at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.loadServerVariables(ConnectionImpl.java:3868)
2020-09-14T15:00:32.411172480Z: [ERROR]                 at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:3407)
2020-09-14T15:00:32.411179480Z: [ERROR]                 at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2384)
2020-09-14T15:00:32.411183580Z: [ERROR]                 at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2153)
2020-09-14T15:00:32.411187681Z: [ERROR]                 at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:792)
2020-09-14T15:00:32.411191981Z: [ERROR]                 at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
2020-09-14T15:00:32.411196181Z: [ERROR]                 at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor36.newInstance(Unknown Source)
2020-09-14T15:00:32.411200282Z: [ERROR]                 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
2020-09-14T15:00:32.411204382Z: [ERROR]                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
2020-09-14T15:00:32.411208482Z: [ERROR]                 at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
2020-09-14T15:00:32.411212483Z: [ERROR]                 at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:381)
2020-09-14T15:00:32.411216483Z: [ERROR]                 at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
2020-09-14T15:00:32.411220583Z: [ERROR]                 at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
2020-09-14T15:00:32.411224684Z: [ERROR]                 at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
2020-09-14T15:00:32.411228784Z: [ERROR]                 at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
2020-09-14T15:00:32.411232884Z: [ERROR]                 at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
2020-09-14T15:00:32.411237085Z: [ERROR]                 ... 32 more
```

Does anyone have an idea why this exception may occur?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether your issue is already resolved.

I was facing the same issue while connecting my Java application to Azure MySQL Server. Application was connecting to local MySQL Server but not Azure MySQL. In my case local MySQL version was 5.6, but Azure MySQL version was set to 8.0. I think this was the cause of the issue.

I had "mysql-connector-java-5.0.8.jar" configured for my application and it was throwing "MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Got packets out of order" error.

I updated the jar to "mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar" and it resolved the issue. Do check your Azure MySQL version and try above solution to see if it resolves the issue.